# Remove item from looped array in underscorejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array like this

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Looping code is like this using `_.each` function in [underscore.js](http://www.underscoejs.org)

```
_.each(array,function(item,index){
  console.log(item);
});
```

But I want remove some items in  array when looping. For example I need to remove number 5 from array and loop does not print number 5.
The question is, is it possible to remove  items in array when looping on this array?

Comment: I'm not familiar with underscore methods, but in a general sense it's not a good idea to remove array items when using an iterator function like `.each()` because (again I'm not sure about underscore, but for some other equivalents) the length of the array may be cached at the beginning so then if you remove items the iterator will run off the end. It's no problem if iterating with a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: @nnnnnn: It is if he forgets `i--` whenever he removes the current element ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With underscore you could do this:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var filteredList = _.filter(array, function(item){

    // do something with each item - here just log the item
    console.log(item);

    // only want even numbers
    return item % 2 == 0;

});

// show filtered list
_.each(filteredList, function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: @VivekJha as pointed out in the comment underneath the question it is not a good idea to modify a collection when iterating over it. This solution returns a modified collection (here only returning even numbers as an example) and showing that you could perform an operation on each item in the collection as you would when iterating (here just performing a console log).

Comment: If you filter out the elements which needs to be deleted, still you need to do a couple of steps to get them actually deleted from the main array. 1. You will have to figure out their indexes 2. Then store the indexes in a list 3. Make sure you reverse sort them 4. The use _.each to splice each index item. I would prefer the answer provided by @ThiefMaster.

Comment: Just replace the `var filteredList = _.filter(...)` with `array = _.filter(...)` and the original array is mutated.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually a very bad idea to modify an array while iterating over it. The best solution is to store the indexes in a separate array and remove them afterwards (remember to iterate over that array from last to first so you don't have to deal with changing indexes).

Comment: Ah, I see now that when I replied to you above you'd already posted about iterating backwards. I'll delete the other comment. +1.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways, I'd recommend the first one.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    items_to_remove = [], i;

_.each(array, function(item,index){
    if(item === 'something'){
        items_to_remove.push(index);
    }
});

while((i = items_to_remove.pop()) != null){
    array.splice(i, 1);
}

// OR
for(i = array.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
    if(array[i] === 'something') {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `for (var i = array.length-1; ...`, no?

Comment: first way go to infinite loop

Comment: did you change anything in it? because it doesn't here :
`var a = [1,2,3,4,5]; while((i = a.pop()) != null) { console.log(i); }` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Undersocre to reduce the line of code. Underscore is an handy-tool.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
array = _.without(array, _.findWhere(array, {
  id: 3
}));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple inline solution that worked for me using underscore's reject function:

```
_.each(_.reject(array, function(arrayItem) { return arrayItem === 5}), function(item){
  console.log(item);
});
```